# Do we need s3 bucket same region with EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Since my company using Sign Url to upload directly to S3 and with accelerated upload. And Cloudfront to download. Do I need the bucket to be same region with out web app. Or I can use US oregon for the S3. The reason to save the cost with since some region cost more than others region.(The S3 Infrequent Access ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using CloudFront, you will use AWS' dedicated backbone to connect to the bucket wherever it is anyway. It does mean increased latency, though, so you should be considerate of what you want (best performance or best cost). Do be aware, too, if you download the same file multiple times the latency is much less of an issue as it will be cached at the Cloudfront edge node.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with what @henry said,

also consider Data-Transfer Cost within regions , sometimes they incur more cost along with storage if kept in a region with a low storage cost